# how to make a periodic piecewise-defined function in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make my own function at matlab, which analytically defined as:

```
x(t)=
{ A, k*T =< t <=k*T+tau 
{ 0, k*T+tau < t < k*T+T
```

I'm trying do that with:

```
A=1
T=2
tau=1
k=0:1:10
t=0:0.1:100
y=A.*(t>=k*T).*(t<=k*T+tau) + (0).*(t>k*T+tau).*(t<k*T+T)
```

after that, I get a message:

```
error: mx_el_ge: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1001, op2 is 1x11)
```

The function should look like a square wave with amplitude = A (A=1 for example).

How do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just define one period (k=1), and repeat k times using `repmat`. Now it is not working because you are logically comparing `t` (length 1001) and `k*T` (length 10).

Alternatively, transpose `k`, and sum over the rows:

```
A=1;
T=2;
tau=1;
k=(0:1:10)';
t=0:0.1:100;

y=sum(A.*(t>=k*T).*(t<=k*T+tau) + (0).*(t>k*T+tau).*(t<k*T+T),1);

plot(t,y)
```

Note: This will only work in your particular example, since the function is zero when 'out of range'.

[image]